# request.getQueryString() should not be null?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts, tiles

I'm debugging an old Struts 1.2 w/ Tiles application running on Oracle App Server 10.1.3. There are some scenarios in which request.getQueryString() seems to improperly return null and it seems to have started doing this without any changes to the application code, indicating that server patching may be a factor. I added some scriptlet code to one of the problematic jsps that's being called via Struts Action in a Tile:

```
request.getMethod(): <%= request.getMethod() %><br />
request.getParameter("cmd"): <%= request.getParameter("cmd") %><br />
request.getQueryString(): <%= request.getQueryString() %><br/>
```

Which produces:

```
request.getMethod(): GET
request.getParameter("cmd"): doThis
request.getQueryString(): null
```

The address in the browser is: https://serverhost:8080/app/ActionName.do?cmd=doThis

I tried using [ieHTTPHeaders](http://www.blunck.info/iehttpheaders.html) and the browser is sending:

```
GET /app/ActionName.do?cmd=doThis HTTP/1.1
```

And getting back:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

So, no redirects or hidden POSTS going on.

Does anyone know if there's any application code or configuration that could lead to this? Otherwise I'll concentrate on the app server/JVM/OS patch levels.

Comment: I'd immediately blame it on Oracle :) 
Try running it on Tomcat, just to test whether it's the same there.

Comment: Works on Tomcat. BUT, also works on one instance of Oracle AS that has different patch levels. I think this is the answer but I wanted to make sure -- see if anyone has other ideas. Thanks Bozho.

Comment: @Bozho: post an answer that the OP should really upgrade/replace his server :)

Comment: +1 well written, well researched question